# RabbitMQ server is already shut down., but python rabbitpy library does not throw error, when I publish a message to the RabbitMQ server

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, rabbitpy

I am using Python 3.5, rabbitpy 2.0.1.
I have created a flask app and I am also using the **eventlet** library with my app.

I have created an app-level **connection** and an app-level **channel**, and I am using that connection & channel between multiple requests to publish a message in RabbitMQ using the rabbitpy library.

**My connection code:**

```
app.conn = rabbitpy.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672/%2f')
app.channel = app.conn.channel()
```

**My publisher code:**

```
message = rabbitpy.Message(app.channel, json.dumps({"test": "test"}))
message.publish('test', 'test', mandatory=True)
```

When I shut down my RabbitMQ server then If I publish a message then it should throw an exception (Like RabbitMQ server is not running) but it is not throwing any exception, so how can I know that my message is published or not?

And in the above situation if I use `channel.enable_publisher_confirms()` , then at that point my program goes into an infinite loop (dead lock) in the function `message.publish('test', 'test', mandatory=True)`, so I can not use it.

Comment: Can not reproduce this problem. After I shut down rabbitmq, the publisher client raise `RuntimeError: Timeout waiting for opening the socket`

Comment: @Spikie Which operating system are you using? I am using windows 10. have you followed the following steps to reproduce the above problem?
1. Create a connection&channel
2. shut down the RabbitMQ server
3. Publish a message.